# Tkinter Treeview selection

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, treeview, ttk

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import tkMessageBox

class Application(Frame) :
    def selected(self):
        curItem = self.tree.focus();
        print self.tree.item(curItem)['values'][0]
        self.quit()

    def __init__(self,master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()

        tree = self.tree = Treeview(self,columns=('Name','Description'),show="headings",selectmode='browse')
        tree.heading("Name", text="Name")
        tree.heading("Description", text="Description")
        tree.grid(padx = 30)

        i = tree.insert('','end',values = ['0353','567'])
        tree.insert(i,'end',values = ['03535','567'])
        Button(self,text = "Submit",command = self.selected).grid()


root = Tk()
app = Application()
app.master.title("Tree view")
app.master.minsize(500, 400)
app.master.protocol(name = "WM_DELETE_WINDOW",func=app.master.quit)

app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

When I try to select "0353" in the tree view and submit it is printing '353' instead of 0353. I want the output to be "0353". I am using python 2.7

Comment: First of all, you're using the widgets not in the most correct and efficient way, lets say. You may want to set the _title_, _minsize_ and _protocol_ properties to the `root` object, and then _pack_ your `app` object on the root... You won't need anyways to do `root.destroy` after  `root.mainloop()` (instead of `app.mainloop`).

Comment: Regarding your specific problem, it seems that the string is converted to a number and the leading zero is then ignored. If instead of printing `print self.tree.item(curItem)['values'][0]`, you print the whole object, lets say, with `print self.tree.item(curItem)`, you also see that `0353` is already represented as `353`. In fact, if you try to print the type of it using `print type(self.tree.item(curItem)['values'][0])`, it outputs `<type 'int'>`...

Comment: Is there any way to avoid that <type 'int'> ? And also why tree view is not showing me some arrow or plus whether it is open or not? How can I get that '+' symbol before every non leaf item?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe my answer comes a bit late ( smile ) ... but ... the problem persists same way also in Python 3.9 . The reason for this problem is an automated conversion of strings to integer values by the tkinter Treeview widget  ( in Python 3  `Tkinter` is named `tkinter` ).

The only way around seems to be accepting that all decimal digit only string entries are preceded by some other character (or characters) than a digit to prevent  `int(entry)` deliver a value instead of an error. This 'header' can be then removed from the returned string value to get the desired value. Below a proposal for the changes required to achieve the desired  result:

```
tree.insert('',tkinter.END,values = ['> 0353','> 567'])

print( self.tree.item(curItem)['values'][0][2:] )
```

By the way: I can remember from the old times of Excel that its users had coped with the same kind of problem of automated type conversion. The above provided solution applies also there.