# Selection from a Treeview automatically converts string numbers to integers

Tags: python, string, tkinter, treeview, selection

In a project that I am working on, you can edit the contents of the data shown in treeview form. One of the fields of data is a telephone number which always starts with a 0.

When selecting the correct record in the table and having the data pulled from it using `tree.item(tree.selection())`. For some reason, the telephone numbers are automatically converted to integers and so they lose the 0 at the start of them when they are displayed to the user in the box.

Is there any way to fix this?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


def fnEdit(tree):
    items = tree.item(tree.selection())
    print(items['values'][0])


myGui = Tk()

container = Frame(myGui)
container.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

editButton = Button(myGui, text='Edit', command=lambda: fnEdit(tree))
editButton.pack(fill="x")

table_header = ['Contact No.']
tree = ttk.Treeview(container, columns=table_header, show="headings")
tree.column(table_header[0])
tree.insert('', 'end', values='01234567895')
tree.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

myGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening (but seems to happen every time a string can also be interpreted as a number), but you have a clumsy workaround: you can convert the integers returned to strings and prepend the necessary zeros.

Comment: @nbro That was the way I thought I could get around it. Not too sure what the exam board would think of it but it's probably the only option I have.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/39067164/7432. Unfortunately, this appears to be a bug in ttk.

Answer (score 2):

By duplicating data from `values` into `text` (*when adding new item to the tree*) and later reading from `text` (instead of `values`), would allow to overcome this limitation.

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import Frame
from tkinter import Button
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# print(TkVersion) 
# 8.6

def edit(tree):
    if len(tree.selection()) == 1:
        selected_item = tree.item(tree.selection())
        #print(selected_item['values'][0])
        print(selected_item['text'])
    else:
        print('please select item')

gui = Tk()

container = Frame(gui)
container.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

edit_button = Button(gui, text='Edit', command=lambda: edit(tree))
edit_button.pack(fill='x')

tree = ttk.Treeview(container, show='headings')

col_names = ['Contact No.']
tree['columns'] = col_names
for col_name in col_names:
    tree.heading(col_name, text=col_name)

phone_nums = ['01234567895']
for phone_num in phone_nums:
    tree.insert('', 'end', text=phone_num, values=phone_num)

tree.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

gui.mainloop()
```