# Why are the digit values in the tkinter items integers and not strings even when I inserted those values as type string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, treeview

the title refers to this problem, I need to get the values under the keyword **values** of **Tkinter TreeView** using the method *item* as in: `tree.item(v)['values'][0]`, *v* being my selection on the treeview. The method returns an integer, and if the value had zeros befores it just ignores them.

Heres an example of what I mean: I need the value marked in yellow exactly as it is (001) instead of (1).
Printing this "tree.item(v)['values'][0]" will say the value it's 1 but the treeview shows the real value 001. How can I get the real value (001)?, Thank you.

[image: I need the value marked in yellow exactly as it is (001) instead of (1)]

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.title('Treeview')
window.configure(background='Yellow Green')

ttk.Label(window, text='There must be colors at some rows:', 
    font=('DejaVu Sans', 11, 'bold'), background= 'yellow green').grid(row=0, column=0)
tree = ttk.Treeview(window, columns=('name', 'surname', 'telephone'))
tree.grid(row=1, column=0)
tree.heading('#0', text='Α/Α')
tree.heading('name', text='Name')
tree.heading('surname', text='Surname')
tree.heading('telephone', text='Telephone')
tree.insert('', 0, text='0001', values=("001",2230310,"Hello"))
c = tree.get_children()
print(tree.get_children())
for v in c:
    print(tree.item(v))
    print(tree.item(v)['text'])
    print(tree.item(v)['values'][0], type(tree.item(v)['values'][0]))
application = (window)
window.mainloop()
```

original code: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=242442

Comment: if you always use 3-digits then you can convert it back to string `number = 1` and `text = f'{number:03}'` and it will add zeros.

Comment: 001 was just the example but can be any data with any number of 0's. What can be done in that case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like tkinter.ttk.Treeview always convert all items in `values` into integer if possible.

Two related issues,

- [Issue 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701981/selection-from-a-treeview-automatically-converts-string-numbers-to-integers)
- [Issue 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067164/tkinter-treeview-selection)

From ttk code, there's no way to stop the conversion by setting any options for it.

So hack code here, it may work for you. Place code after you import `ttk` and before your use `ttk.Treeview`.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def _convert_stringval(value):
    """Converts a value to, hopefully, a more appropriate Python object."""
    if hasattr(value, 'typename'):
        value = str(value)
        try:
            value = int(value)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass
    return value

ttk._convert_stringval = _convert_stringval
```

Note: It may not work if tkinter update something related in the future.